# How can Kurumi Tokisaki's clone be killed twice?

Tags: date-a-live

In the anime series *Date A Live* to *Date A Live II*, there was this clone of Kurumi that had feelings for Shido. In seasons 1-2, the same clone was killed twice by Kurumi. The first was on the school rooftop and the second was in the festival. I finished the anime a while ago and there was some question that is bugging me.

How can the same clone be killed twice? Had the first death didn't kill her fully? If the first death killed her fully, then how did she manage to come back to meet Shido? And is it possible that the same clone will come back again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the same clone can be killed twice. This is based from her ability, the eight bullet: Het, which creates a clone of a target object or subject. The clones she makes from herself are her past selves. As said from the wiki:

> Combined with the power of the 8th bullet, she can create a clone that has all her experiences, memories, abilities, etc. These clones can take the form of long white hands with red outlining when they are in Kurumi's shadows. However, as these are her past selves, they sometimes may contain feelings which the current Kurumi no longer possesses and as such, Kurumi will not hesitate to kill these clones if they choose to disobey her.

The very concept of her abilities are not very specific in my opinion. But, so far, this is what I've observed based from the show, and from those who've read the light novels.

You can check out her full set of abilities here if you have any doubts:

[Kurumi's Powers and Abilities](http://date-a-live.wikia.com/wiki/Kurumi_Tokisaki#Powers_and_Abilities)

Answer (score 1):

The clones are versions of her from the past and the future, but they can also travel through time and space, meaning that one had travelled from a time before it was killed by the other Kurumi to see Shido. So therefore it wasn't as much of cloning as it was summoning past and future versions of herself and having an instant army, which I think is freaking op. I mean she's so unstable, it's scary, so if you think about it, her only weakness is that summoning these other Kurumi's takes away from the time she has to live. So, yeah, based on what has been given away, one of her foot soldiers can be killed more than once